# What to do when this type of error occurs?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm trying to install hive. I have searched this error on internet and tried different ways to solve it, but I can't.

So, please help me to solve this error.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!!**

```
*SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-hive-2.3.3-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-3.0.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/apache-hive-2.3.3-bin/lib/hive-common-2.3.3.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these are errors.

Both Hadoop and Hive use overlapping logging libraries, as long as nothing conflicts, only one is chosen, and that warning is shown

The last line is encouraging you to install Apache Tez or Spark and configure the Hive execution engine to use that rather than Mapreduce, and if you want to use MapReduce, then install Hive 1.x instead

---

In any case, Hive 2.x doesn't support Hadoop 3.x